# How to change one specific element in a matrix?

Tags: python, list, matrix, tuples

I have initialized my matrix as ...

```
mid_mtx = [ [(0, "")]*len(s2) ]*len(s1)
```

I later created a list that holds two value [ 6, "Middle" ] called middle_ij_val.

I want to update mid_mtx[i][j] with middle_ij_val.
so i did...

```
mid_mtx[i][j] = middle_ij_val
```

However, this would output ...

```
[(0, ''), [6, 'Middle'], (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')]

[(0, ''), [6, 'Middle'], (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')]

[(0, ''), [6, 'Middle'], (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')]

[(0, ''), [6, 'Middle'], (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')]

[(0, ''), [6, 'Middle'], (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')]

[(0, ''), [6, 'Middle'], (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')]
```

How would I code it so that if I do mid_mtx[1][1] it will only change that specific place only?

Comment: mid_mtx[i][j] = middle_ij_val is within a double for loop that iterates all the elements in the matrix. Iterating row is the outer for loop and col is the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[(0, "")] * len(s2)] * len(s1)
```

Above expression create a list with same element repeated, instead of different items. All items are same item; changing one item affects all.

In other word, `mid_mtx[0] is mid_mtx[1]`, `mid_mtx[0] is mid_mtx[2]`, ....
or, `id(mid_mtx[0]) == id(mid_mtx[1])`, `id(mid_mtx[0]) == id(mid_mtx[2])`, ...

---

```
[[(0, "") for j in s2] for i in s1]
```

Above list comprehension will create a list with independent items.

Because the inner-most items are tuple (immutable), you can use following instead:

```
[[(0, "")] * len(s2) for i in s1]
```